# How to trace incoming requests with AWS X-Ray on Spring Boot WebFlux?

Tags: spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux, servlet-filters, aws-xray

I have multiple microservices running on AWS ECS and I want to try out AWS X-Ray. Following [this developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-java-filters.html) I added a `WebConfig.java` file with a tracing filter.

Added lines to `build.gradle`:

```
implementation "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1"
implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-xray-recorder-sdk-core:2.8.0"
```

New file `WebConfig.java`:

```java
import com.amazonaws.xray.javax.servlet.AWSXRayServletFilter;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

  @Bean
  public Filter tracingFilter() {
    return new AWSXRayServletFilter("ordermicroservice");
  }
}
```

However, I don't think this is correct, mostly because I had to add the extra dependency for the `javax.servlet.Filter`. I think this is because I'm using spring-boot-webflux and not spring-boot-web. So I have a Netty webserver and not a Tomcat webserver.

My questions are:

- How can I add logging to a servlet filter, to make sure that every incoming HTTP request is passing correctly through the filter?
- What is the correct way to write a web filter in spring-boot-webflux projects, which use Netty and not Tomcat?

Edit:
By now I figured out how to write a filter with Spring Boot WebFlux. I will add it to the question here for future reference:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono

@Component
class MyCustomWebFilter : WebFilter {

    override fun filter(webExchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        print("Successfully reached the WebFilter.\n")

        val request = webExchange.request
        val response = webExchange.response

        // TODO: Do the actual filtering by looking at the request and modifying the response

        return chain.filter(webExchange)
    }
}
```

Comment: you're correct. A servlet filter won't work when you are using webflux. The equivalent of the servlet filter in webflux is the WebFilter. All you need to do is create an new implementation of the WebFilter interface and add the component annotation to it.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/WebFilter.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Michael, you may need to implement the WebFilter interface. Since the AWSXRayServletFilter is a servlet filter, it won't work with WebFilter. Unfortunately there is no built-in support in X-Ray SDK for WebFlux yet. What you'll need to do is within your WebFilter chain, implement an interceptor of your own for tracing incoming requests by creating a segment and adding relevant data to it. You can reference how the AWSXRayServletFilter traces incoming requests here: https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-xray-recorder-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/xray/javax/servlet/AWSXRayServletFilter.java

Or, you can use the OpenTelemetry Java SDK to instrument your application and use AWS Collector to send trace data to X-Ray. The OTel SDK has support for WebFlux framework. You can find more info below.

OTel Java SDK instrumentation: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation

AWS OTel Collector: https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/collector

Comment: Ok, so just to be completely clear, I have to write code myself, which looks at the headers of the incoming request, and if there is no x-ray-tracing-header yet, add it to the outgoing response?

Comment: Mostly yes. You'll have to write quite a bit of code by yourself to trace the incoming request. You may not require to add the x-ray tracing header to the outgoing response though if you don't plan to use it anywhere. The key parts are intercepting the request, creating a segment, adding required data to segment, end the segment on the response back.

Comment: Also see the alternative to use OpenTelemetry in my answer above.